# How to get Column Header Text on double click

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to take the ColumnHeader Text of the ColumnHeader that has been double clicked. This is what I've gotten so far. It doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string TheDate = dataGridView1.SelectedColumns.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(TheDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get index of column through `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` object e and use to get the `HeaderText`

```
string text = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
{
    string theDate = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
}
```